# Are locked tables accessible by included scripts?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script that instantiates two different classes for use.

If I lock the tables that they need to read/write to from the "parent" script, would the class instances be able to use the locked tables?

I have the suspicion that because they share the same db connection they will be able to do so and that the lock will be held until the "parent" script releases it.

Am I correct?

Comment: When you say "parent" do you mean that you are forking child processes, or are you just including one script in another?

Comment: include/require the script that has the class code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Included scripts become a part of the script which includes them, just as if you copied the code from the included script and pasted it into the main one. There is no parent/child separation.

Consequently, you will be able to access your tables via the included script as long as you are using the same database connection.

Comment: Just for arguments sake, that wouldn't be the case if the classes each opened their own connection to the db and tried to access the tables that were locked by the "parent" script, correct?

Comment: Correct. The database connection must be shared. New connections cannot access the locked tables, even if the connections are initiated by the same script.